# How do you keep a PHP link in the header while it loads another page?

Tags: php

If you go here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120903235224/http://getriotpointscodes.com/ and look at the PHP coded link on the right hand side (hxxp://getriotpointscodes.com/index.php?id=35863).

How do you mimic the behavior where you copy the link into the browser while it loads another page while keeping the original clicked link (hxxp://getriotpointscodes.com/index.php?id=35863) as the header?

This page is already exhibiting this behavior, but I wasn't sure how to exactly code it for my own use.

I had something like this, but it's probably wrong:

```
<?php
// referral.php

$id = (isset($_GET["id"])) ? strval($_GET["id"]) : "1";
// lookup
$url[1] = 'hxxp://getriotpointscodes.com/index.php?id=23121';

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
include("index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate a bit on what you want to acchieve. See also: [How to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve this in all browsers is by using a single-frame frameset.

However, frames are deprecated and the behaviour you mention is a very bad thing - for example, it prevents the user from properly bookmarking a page

If both links are on the same domain you could also use the HTML5 `history.pushState` JavaScript API to modify the displayed URL.

Comment: Well if you visit that page and copy the link on the right side. Can you tell me how to mimic that behavior? How is he displaying the index page from the php coded link id tag but keeping it the header?